# How to store Json data into Sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

I have created one project like news update and i have saved in UITableView  using JSON api to retrieving the data. now i'm getting problem like if internet is not there means records will not show to the user. now i'm planning to create data base like .sqlite. friends please help in crating data base. i'm new to this

Comment: Explicit usage of SQLite is now discouraged, best way is to use Core Data (which is embedded in iOS SDK). There are also ton of tutorials on this subject. I remember I liked this one: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply save the json to a text file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

[jsonString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

and then read it:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the link that will useful for beginners like you..[Database with ios](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx)
cheers